# How to make bootstrap clickable-row unavailable for a specific columns?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap` and I have a clickable row there. When you click the row a `model` will open. It is like below.

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" style="cursor:pointer">
```

However in this row, there is a columns which contains a button. The issue is the button get clicked, but since the entire row is clickable, the `model` get opened first, then the button's commands get executed.

Below is the button column.

```
<td>
  <form>
     <label>
         <input type="submit" name="buttonActDea" id="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Activate">
      </label>
   </form>
</td>
```

How can I make the "clickable row" feature un-available only for the button column?

Comment: @madalinivascu: That is what I am asking how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's [stopPropagation();](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('#button').on('click',function(e) {
    //button function

    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

or remove the data atributes so the click event for the `tr` isn't triggered if it has a `button` child

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.clickable-row').each(function () {
   if ( $(this).find('#button').length)
     {
       $(this).removeAttr('data-toggle').removeAttr('data-target');
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: other solution is to remove the data atributes that the click event for the tr trigers when the tr has a button as a child so that the click event isn't tied to the tr

Comment: I do not understand your answers as I am not familliar with designing.

Comment: @JustCause http://jsfiddle.net/xfb47vz7/3/ this is what madalinivascu is talking about. So the stopPropagation actualy has to work if you bind it right.